# GPG: Can't encrypt DSA 3072 keys

Tags: encryption, privacy, gnupg, dsa

I would like to ask this question as I'm not the first person which has
this behavior.

I'm trying to encrypt a simple message using GnuPG using a public key I've 
received from a friend, he's using DSA 3072 but for some reason, 
whenever I try to encrypt using his public key, I get

```
gpg: <mailaddr>: skipped: unusable public key
gpg: s: encryption failed: unusable public key
```

Here's the output of gpg --list-key when I lookup my friend's mail

```
pub   3072D/fingerprint some-date-here
uid                  Name1 <mail1>
uid                  Name2 <mail2>
```

Here's my GPG --version output

```
gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.19
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, RSA-E, RSA-S, ELG-E, DSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

I'm asking here as I recently got mail from people claiming the same (I'm also using DSA 3072 on my key).
Can anyone shed some light on this topic ?

Answer (score 2):

DSA is a signature algorithm; its keys are not usable for asymmetric encryption. In the [OpenPGP format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880), algorithms for encryption are RSA and El-Gamal.

Normally, when you create your keypair, you are actually producing several key pairs: a "master" key, and some "sub-keys" for signing and for encrypting. The master key signs the sub-keys. When you say that you use "DSA 3072", you really mean that your master key uses DSA 3072. Similarly for your friend.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the semantic correction. 
but why can't I use "gpg --reciepent "person" --encrypt " ? why does it give an error ?

Comment: The idea is that, for some reason, you have a copy of the recipient's master key (usable for signatures only) but not of his encryption subkey. `gpg` only sees the signature key, and cannot use it for encryption.

Comment: which software should i use instead of gpg then in order to encrypt using it ?

Comment: also, doesn't "Pubkey: ... DSA" states that my version of GPG supports DSA?

Comment: GPG supports DSA and DSA is a signature algorithm, so GPG will be perfectly happy to verify signatures using that key. That's the point of DSA being a signature algorithm and not an encryption algorithm: you can sign with it, you cannot encrypt with it.

Comment: but still when I generate a keypair using GnuPG I can use DSA and ElGamal, what's the case here ? This key isn't unique, it was generated in a default way